# Como alterar o layout de um radar plot para Circumplex (Polar Bar) Charts no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando alterar o layout de um radar plot. Não consigo que o gráfico tenha a aparência abaixo. Todas as tentativas geraram gráficos em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou tentando modificar:

```
# Libraries
library(fmsb)

# Create data: 
set.seed(1)
dados <-as.data.frame(matrix (sample ( 0:100, 13090 , replace=T) , ncol=17, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(dados) <- c ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17")

# To use the fmsb package, I have to add 2 lines to the dataframe: the max and min of each topic to show on the plot!
dados <- rbind(rep(100,17) , rep(0,17) , dados)

# Loop for each plot
for(i in 1:10){
  
  png(filename = paste0('C:\\Users\\Clarice\\Pictures\\',i,'.png'))
  
  
  # Custom the radarChart !
  radarchart( dados[c(1,2,i+2),], axistype=1, 
              #custom polygon
              pcol=rgb(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.5) , plwd=2  , 
              
              #custom the grid
              cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,50,100), cglwd=0.6,
              
              #custom labels
              vlcex=0.9,
              
  )
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Tente fornecer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Remova todas as bibliotecas, dados e partes do código que não dizem respeito à sua dúvida. Usuários devem ser capazes de copiar e colar seu código em um ambiente limpo, rodá-lo e chegar no mesmo erro, sem mais nem menos. Isso também é útil para você, é uma prática que ajuda a detectar e isolar onde está o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazê-lo com ggplot2, é um gráfico de barras com coordenada polar no eixo X:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- data.frame(x = paste("Grupo", 1:9), y = mtcars$disp[1:9])

ggplot(dados, aes(x, y, fill = x)) +
  geom_col(color = "white", width = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta e feedback. Seguirei as orientações nas próximas postagens.

Comment: [Não precisa agradecer, apenas use o sistema de pontuação do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)